# How do I sort a multidimensional table in Lua?

Tags: arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, lua, lua-table

I have a table consisting basically of the following:

```
myTable = {{1, 6.345}, {2, 3.678}, {3, 4.890}}
```

and I'd like to sort the table by the decimal values. 
So I'd like to the output to be:

```
{{2, 3.678}, {3, 4.890}, {1, 6.345}}
```

If possible, I'd like to use the table.sort() function. Thankyou in advance for the help :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that your table is a sequence, you can use `table.sort` directly. This function accepts a comparison predicate as its second argument, which prescribes the comparison logic:

```
require 'table'

myTable = {{1, 6.345}, {2, 3.678}, {3, 4.890}}

table.sort(myTable, function(lhs, rhs) return lhs[2] < rhs[2] end)
```

Printing the table e.g. as `for _, v in ipairs(myTable) do print(v[1], v[2]) end` then shows the desired ordering:

> ```
> 2       3.678
> 3       4.89
> 1       6.345
> ```

They key here is not the dimension of the table to sort, but the fact that it is a sequence, i.e. ordered.